# Text (preferably centered with the first line in bold) to the side of included graphics in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, positioning

I have a document with a main heading followed by a picture with some contact information to the right of it. After that the other subheadings continue.

[image]

I want to do the same in LaTeX. Which I am actually quite familiar with. Which method would you recommend to get the same layout using LaTeX? I really want to use this layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I’m not sure what exactly you want but if it’s simply a picture side by side with some text, then two minipages will help:

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{…}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  Some text
\end{minipage}
```

Be sure not to leave any space between the two minipages though (hence the `%` comment at the end of the first), otherwise the minipages won’t fit and be broken apart.

Comment: You could add how to center the text in the 2nd minipage as requested in the _title_.

Comment: You could also mention that a `\noindent` command before the first `minipage` environment could be necessary.