# How do I put an image on the left of right-aligned text

Tags: graphics, positioning

I'm trying to add an image to the top left corner of a page (inside the margins) in LaTeX. Across from the image I want a set of right-aligned text. I tried using two columns but the image is smaller than the text and it breaks up some of the longer lines of text. Didn't seem to be able to make columns of different width with the `multicol` package.

Here is an example of what I want (made in open office):

[image: What I want]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Text (preferably centered with the first line in bold) to the side of included graphics in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14238/5764)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use two `minipage`s next to each other:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}% just to show the page margins

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove demo option in actual document

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{yourimage}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}\raggedleft
Yesterday,\\
all my troubles seemed so far away\\
Now it looks as though they're here to stay\\
Oh, I believe in yesterday.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another screenshot with `\fbox`es around the `minipage`s and with `\dotfill` instead of `\hfill` to make it more obvious how this is constructed. (You wouldn't ever use this in an actual document, obviously.)

[image]

Comment: This would be a nice example to show the benefit of `microtype` ... :)

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked perfectly! Just learning TeX this last few days.

Comment: @LyleGordon: Glad I could help, you've come to the right place when looking for help or just for new things to learn. In case you don't know it already, I highly recommend [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), which is where I started. Section 6.6 is about `minipage` and friends ...

Answer (score 7):

Use minipage.
Put each section inside a minipage and specify the required linewidth for each.
Example:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{expectation.PNG}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}\raggedleft
This test is supposed\\
to be algnes\\
to left\\
\end{minipage}
\noindent
\\
this is perfect it seems
```

[image: Finally, it will look like:]

Comment: oops!  if it's to be aligned to the left, you mean `\raggedright`.  (welcome to tex.sx.)