# Bringhurst chapter style in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I'm trying to imitate Robert Bringhurst's chapter style in `memoir`. The class includes one such chapter style, but does *not* typeset the chapter number on the right side margin, as in Bringhurst's book. This is a sample of Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style* (grabbed from Amazon):

[image: Bringhurst]

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{Bringhurst}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
   \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
       \hspace{\textwidth}%
       \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
     }%
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
   \raggedright\large\scshape\MakeUppercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
  \vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip\onelineskip}}
\makeatother
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
  \chapterstyle{Bringhurst}
  \chapter{This Is My First Chapter}
  \kant[3]
\end{document}
```

which renders thus:

[image: mine]

How can I fix my code in order lower the chapter number to the level of the first text line before the chapter title?

Comment: I was thinking in using `textpos` package, but there must surely be a simpler way.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can tell you that Eivind Uggedal's Master's thesis using classicthesis.sty has what you are looking for. It (PDF) and source are freely available on the web.

Comment: @bennettr: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This site focuses more on Questions and Answers- it's a little different from other forum-based sites :) I've flagged this answer, so it will probably be converted to a comment

Comment: See http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is a third suggestion, this time using [`xcoffins`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins). It has an easy and intuitive way of handling boxes that need to be joined, attached, shifted... one should note, though, that [`xcoffins`' syntax might still change in the future](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover/17580#comment32780_17580).

The basic idea is simple: define coffins (i.e. boxes)

```
\NewCoffin\testA
\NewCoffin\testB
```

set them to contain what you like

```
\SetHorizontalCoffin\testA{\huge A}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\testB{bbb}
```

rotate, scale or resize them, join (bounding box is extended to contain both, `\JoinCoffins`) or attach (bounding box is not extended, `\JoinCoffins*`) them using so-called handles or poles and maybe used some horizontal or vertical offset

```
% join bottom center of \testA with top center of \testB
% and shift \testB 1em down:
\JoinCoffins\testA[hc,b]\testB[hb,t](0pt,-1em)
```

and finally typeset them:

```
\TypesetCoffin\testA
```

This is all very well explained [in the documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xcoffins).

I use this idea below using three coffins: `\main` is used as a shell that will be filled with contents and typeset in the end. `\titleline` is filled with a horizontal ruled and joined with `\main`, `\chapternumber` is filled with the scaled and coloured chapter number for numbered chapters or is left empty else. It is then attached to main and shifted into the margin and (what seemed an appropriate amount) down:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% not then font used by Bringhurst, but anyway:
\usepackage{libertine}
% we want to letterspace uppercased words and those in small caps, so:
\usepackage{microtype}

% the chapter style:
\usepackage{xcoffins,xcolor}
\NewCoffin\main
\NewCoffin\titleline
\NewCoffin\chapternumber

\makechapterstyle{Bringhurst}{%
  \renewcommand*\chapterheadstart{}
  \renewcommand*\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand*\chapternamenum{}
  \renewcommand*\afterchapternum{}
  % numbered chapters:
  \renewcommand*\printchapternum{%
      \SetHorizontalCoffin\chapternumber{%
      \textcolor{black!10}{\thechapter}%
    }%
    \ScaleCoffin\chapternumber{8}{8}%
  }
  % unnumbered chapters:
  \renewcommand*\printchapternonum{\SetHorizontalCoffin\chapternumber{}}
  \renewcommand*\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \memRTLraggedright\normalfont\large\MakeUppercase{\textls[75]{##1}}}
  \renewcommand*\afterchaptertitle{%
    \vskip.5\onelineskip
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\titleline{\color{black!50}\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}%
    \JoinCoffins\main\titleline
    \JoinCoffins*\main\chapternumber(\textwidth+\marginparsep,-4\baselineskip)%
    \TypesetCoffin\main
    \vskip\onelineskip
  }
}

\chapterstyle{Bringhurst}

% sections and subsections:
\setsecnumformat{\normalfont\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}

% the section style:
\newcommand\uppercasehead[1]{%
  \noindent\normalfont\scshape\MakeLowercase{\textls[50]{#1}}}
\setsecindent{0pt}
\setsecheadstyle{\uppercasehead}

% the subsection style:
\newcommand\itshapehead[1]{\normalfont\itshape#1}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\itshapehead}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

% the subsubsection style:
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\itshapehead}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{The Grand Design}
\section{First Principles}
\subsection{Typography exists to honor content}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about this package.

Comment: It's very handy to design [all sorts of layouts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44159/5049) ([titlepages...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17580/5049))

Comment: xcoffins is useful but this doesn't address what I thought was the main issue in the question of attaching the number to the first line of _text_ even if there are intervening (section or subsection) headings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't read that from the question but maybe I'm mistaken. Anyway, it's not how it's set in Bringhurst's _Elements_ - the chapter number is always set relative to the rule beneath the title there (I've checked my copy just to be sure)

Comment: yes I know:-) well anyway you got the tick so that's OK, I just thought I'd note for the record that I answered a different question in the code below, would have beem much easier otherwise, as you show to drop the number in the afterheading code, I was guided (mislead?) by the phrase "first text line"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, my phrasing wasn't precise. I meant the first piece of text (body text or subheadings) after the chapter heading.

Comment: Is there a way to make this chapter style work under XeTeX? I always get `Package microtype error: Letterspacing currently doesn't work with xetex.`

Comment: Never mind, [I realized](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211829/letterspacing-via-microtype-vs-fontspec-in-lualatex) that I just had to remove calls to microtype's `\textls` and use fontspec's `LetterSpace` option instead.

Answer (score 32):

This lines the baseline of the number with the baseline of the text, you may want to raise it a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{Bringhurst}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
   \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
   \raggedright\large\scshape\MakeUppercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
  \vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip\onelineskip
\gdef\insertchapnum{%
\global\let\insertchapnum\relax
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
       \hspace{\textwidth}%
       \smash{\resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\color[rgb]{.5,.5,.5}\chapnumfont \thechapter}}}}%
}}

\def\@afterheading{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
      \if@afterindent \else
        {\setbox\z@\lastbox\insertchapnum}%
      \fi
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}}


\makeatother
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
  \chapterstyle{Bringhurst}
  \chapter{This Is My First Chapter}
\section{A section title in the way}
  \kant[3]

aaa
\end{document}
```

In the above, `\@afterheading` which is the code LaTeX inserts to suppress indentation of the first paragraph of a section is redefined to insert a token `\insertchapnum` after removing the indentation.  `\chapter` defines `\insertchapnum` to use the code you had to insert a number (I just made it grey rather than black) and then globally redefine `\insertchapnum` to `\relax` so it does nothing until the next `\chapter` command defines it again.

Comment: Thanks! Nice result. But could you explain the code, please?

Comment: note added as requested

Answer (score 32):

I have been playing with page layouts, and have carefully reproduced aspects of Bringhurst's design, including an explicit calculation of the page parameters, measure, etc.  The result was achieved using the `titlesec` package, placing the chapter number with the `marginnote` package:

```
% Set the font
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,
                     Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, % E.g. -- -> en-dash
             Numbers=OldStyle,
             UprightFeatures={LetterSpace=-0.9},
             ItalicFeatures={LetterSpace=0.9},    % To cancel -0.9 tracking
             SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=10.0},
             ]{Minion Pro}

\setkomafont{marginnote}{
  \addfontfeature{UprightFeatures={LetterSpace=5}}%
  \addfontfeature{ItalicFeatures={LetterSpace=5}}%
  \fontsize{7pt}{9pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{chapternumber}{%
  \fontspec[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
  \fontsize{72pt}{72pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\addfontfeature{UprightFeatures={LetterSpace=15.0}}}

\setkomafont{section}{\scshape}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\itshape}

% Chapters open on the right page.
\KOMAoptions{open=right}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
% Chapter formatting
\titleformat{name=\chapter}
            [block]
            {} % format
            {\marginnote{\usekomafont{chapternumber}\thechapter}
                        [3\baselineskip]} % label
            {0pt} % separation between label and heading
            {\raggedright\usekomafont{chapter}\MakeTextUppercase} % before
            [\trule] % after
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-\topskip}{0pt}

% Bringuest has the whole text flush left, so do not typeset the label
% independently here or the text will hang.
\titleformat{name=\section}
            {\usekomafont{section}} % format
            {} % label
            {0pt} % separation between label and heading
            {\thesection\hspace{0.5em}\MakeTextLowercase} % before
\titleformat{name=\subsection}
            {\usekomafont{subsection}} % format
            {} % label
            {0pt} % separation between label and heading
            {\raggedright{\normalfont\thesubsection}\hspace{0.5em}} % before

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{\baselineskip} 
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
```

The complete source is too long to post (it includes a modification to `geometry` that allows page changes in the middle of a document, and explores other typographic styles) but is available on GitLab: [Exploring Typography with LaTeX](https://gitlab.com/mforbes/exploring-typography-with-latex/overview).  Here is [the result](https://gitlab.com/mforbes/exploring-typography-with-latex/-/raw/branch/default/exploring.pdf):

[image: Sample layout of Chapter 3]
[image: Page layout with Hexagonal Pattern]

As you can see, I am still having some problems with the margin-notes, but the spacing, measure, and positioning of the chapter number is almost identical to Bringhurst's design (as a demonstration of how to do this in LaTeX rather than a suggestion that one should strive to exactly reproduce this style.)

**Update**

Here are the same ideas applied to the `memoir` class.  Note: I am not fluent in `memoir` and had a little bit of difficulty getting the space before the section heads properly adjusted, so the vertical alignment is not exactly correct here (and I have not adjusted the page size etc.  I just blindly set the text box to match Bringhurst's measurements.)

Note also that Bringhurst places the chapter numbers at the same vertical position regardless of the title text: it does not move up or down with the first line of text so that it will always be in the same place for a reader flipping through pages in the book.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xparse}      % So we can define \trule with two optional args
\usepackage{xcolor}

% This rule will take exactly \baselinskip space, maintaining the grid. The
% raise value is the height above the next baseline. It will extend down
% thickness.
% \trule[thickness][raise]
\NewDocumentCommand\trule{O{0.4pt}O{0pt}}{
  \vskip0pt\vtop to0pt{
    \noindent\raisebox{#2}{\vbox{\leavevmode\hrule height#1}}}
}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,
                     Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, % E.g. -- -> en-dash
             Numbers=OldStyle,
             UprightFeatures={LetterSpace=-0.9},
             ItalicFeatures={LetterSpace=0.9},    % To cancel -0.9 tracking
             SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=10.0},
             ]{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\settypeblocksize{496.32431pt}{255.8827pt}{1.25}
\makechapterstyle{Bringhurst}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setsecnumdepth{subsection}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}
               {\normalfont%
                 \addfontfeature{UprightFeatures={LetterSpace=15.0}}}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{%
    \fontspec[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
    \fontsize{72pt}{72pt}\selectfont
    \color{black!30}}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \marginnote{\chapnumfont \thechapter}[3\baselineskip]
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
    \chaptitlefont\raggedright\MakeUppercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\trule\vspace{\oneline}}

  \setsecindent{0pt}
  \setbeforesecskip{\onelineskip}
  \setaftersecskip{\onelineskip}
  \setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\scshape\raggedright\MakeLowercase}

  \setaftersubsecskip{\onelineskip}
  \setsubsecindent{0pt}
  \setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\raggedright\itshape}
}

\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
  \chapterstyle{Bringhurst}
  \chapter{The Grand Design}
  \section{First Principles}
  \subsection{Typography exists to honour content}
  Like oratory, music, dance, calligraphy -- like anything that lends
  its grace to language\ldots

  \kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of Chapter 1 in memoir]

Comment: Thanks! Nice answer! But I'm submerged in `memoir` and don't like very much the `Koma` classes.

Comment: @NVaughan: Okay.  Here is a memoir version.  Note: I have never used memoir before, so am not sure of proper memoir style -- feel free to correct any mistakes.  (Also, I had a bit of difficulty with the vertical spacing, so the vertical spacing is not exactly correct.)  Anyway, it should give you enough to play with if you want to use the `marginnote` solution.

Comment: OK! It looks quite similar to the original! Thanks. (Notice, however, that in `memoir` you don't need the `marginnote` package, as the class has good support for non-float margin notes.)

Comment: @mforbes I try to use your memoir version, it work great in general. I have a problem with the text which don't adapt to the page size A4 :/

Comment: @reyman64 I am not really sure what you are asking: Bringhurst's page layout is tailored to a 5.2"x9" page.  A4 paper requires a totally different layout (two-columns, or maybe very large margin-notes, etc.)

Comment: @mforbes, oh ok, i understand, sorry, my question is silly... But is there any way to keep only the great typography dynamic in an A4 page ? So, with a little less margin ?

Comment: @reyman64 You will have to be more specific.  I just specified a specific typeblock `\settypeblocksize{496.32431pt}{255.8827pt}{1.25}`.  You can change this to anything you like, but there are quite a few design principles you should consider when laying out the page, as discussed in Bringhurst's book for example.  I would suggest asking a new question with a specific request and with an example that shows what you have tried so far.  (As I said: I am not a memoir expert, so someone else is probably better suited to answer your question.)

Answer (score 12):

Another try using `textpos`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{Bringhurst}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}%
  \newlength{\numXpos}%
  \newlength{\numYpos}%
  \setlength{\numXpos}{\hoffset + 1in + \oddsidemargin + \textwidth + \marginparsep}%
  \setlength{\numYpos}{\voffset + 1in + \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep + 3\onelineskip}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
     \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(\numXpos,\numYpos)
       \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
     \end{textblock*}
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
   \raggedright\large\scshape\MakeUppercase{##1}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
  \vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip\onelineskip}}
\makeatother
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
  \headstyles{bringhurst}
  \chapterstyle{Bringhurst}
  \chapter{This Is My First Chapter}
  \section{A section title in the way}
  \kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]