# Puzzle: How to compute Bringhurst's page style with TeX/Metapost/TikZ etc

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, tkz-euclide

In his book *The Elements of Typographic Style*, Bringhurst presents a hexagonal pattern for geometrically constructing the elements of the page layout.

**Question:** Can the dimensions be simply extracted geometrically using [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/), [tkz-eu­clide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide), [Metafont/post](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), or similar LaTeX packages?  *(Geometric elegance is key here, not just a brute force solution demonstrating that TeX is turing complete, and hence can solve the implicit problem.)*

I originally thought that this would be a great example of the geometric methods available through, for example, [tkz-eu­clide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide), but have been unable to come up with an explicit construction.  Of course, one can follow the construction through to obtain an implicit set of equations with a unique solution which I have used to calculate the parameters in the following code, but can one solve the problem elegantly using the geometric methods found in these packages?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.2in/1cm/2]
    \path (0,0) coordinate[label=below:{ll}] (ll)
    -- (1,0) coordinate[label=below:{lr}] (lr)
    -- ++(60:1) coordinate[label=right:{r}] (r)
    -- ++(120:1) coordinate[label=above:{ur}] (ur)
    -- ++(180:1) coordinate[label=above:{ul}] (ul)
    -- ++(240:1) coordinate[label=left:{l}] (l)
    -- ++(300:1) coordinate (ll);
    \coordinate[label=below right:{a}] 
                  (a) at (1.27106916798686, 0.469505571318668);
    \coordinate (tll) at (0.117300021398114, 0.294835256924744);
    \coordinate (tlr) at (0.798192881206518, 0.294835256924744);
    \coordinate (tur) at (0.798192881206518, 1.61553741320908);
    \coordinate (tul) at (0.117300021398114, 1.61553741320908);
    \coordinate[label=below:{x}] (x) at (0.435936138301, 0);
    \coordinate[label=above:{y}] (y)   at (0.689095323638, 1.73205080756888);
    \tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=2,xmin=-0.5,xmax=2]
    \tkzInterLL(l,ur)(a,ul) \tkzGetPoint{A}
    \tkzInterLL(ll,y)(ul,a) \tkzGetPoint{B}
    \tkzInterLL(l,ur)(ll,y) \tkzGetPoint{C} 
    \tkzInterLL(ll,a)(l,x) \tkzGetPoint{D}
    \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C) \tkzGetPoint{U} \tkzGetLength{rU}
    \tkzDefCircle[in](tll,tlr,D) \tkzGetPoint{L} \tkzGetLength{rL}

    % Locate page number
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[L](1,0){Lr}
    \tkzInterLL(L,Lr)(tur,tlr) \tkzGetPoint{pagenumber}

    % Locate running header
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[U](0,\rU pt){Uu}
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[Uu](1,0){Uur}
    \tkzInterLL(Uu,Uur)(y,r) \tkzGetPoint{header}

    \color{black};
    \draw (ll) -- (lr) -- (r) -- (ur) -- (ul) -- (l) -- cycle;
    \color{gray};
    \draw (ur) -- (l) -- (x) -- (r) -- (y) -- (ll) -- (a) -- (ul);
    \draw (l) -- (ur);
    \draw (tul) -- (tur) -- (tlr) -- (tll) -- cycle;
    \draw (ul) -- (ur) -- (lr) -- (ll) -- cycle;

    \tkzSetUpLine[color=gray]
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](U, \rU pt)
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](L, \rL pt)
    \tkzDrawSegments(Uu,header L,pagenumber)
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Bringhurst's page layout with Hexagonal Pattern]

**Update:** To clarify the problem, in addition to the intersection constraints implicit in the picture, one must also impose that the textblock be rectangular with strict vertical/horizontal orientation.  This, along with the constraints that the points lie within the hexagon (not somewhere outside) are enough to ensure that the solution is unique up to an overall scaling that is fixed by the roughly 5.2"x9" physical paper size used for Bringhurst's book.  (As mentioned by @percusse, the hexagon gives an exact ratio `5.2:5.2*2*cos(30º)` = `5.2:9.006664202...`.)

The construction can be completely specified with simple geometric intersections etc. if two numbers are specified.  In particular, one can specify the fraction `y` along `ul--ur` and `x` along `ll--lr` (`z.y=y[z.ul,z.ur]` and `z.x=x[z.ll,z.lr]` in metapost notation).

The exact solution can be found algebraically to be:

```
q = (81 - √3186)^(1/3)
y = q/3 - 2 + 5/q ≈ 0.689095323637659465372247907...
x = (y^2 + 4*y + 3)/(-2*y^2 - 4*y + 18) ≈ 0.4359361383008273751170828497...
```

Additional consistent solutions exist, but the points `x` and `y` lie outside of the corresponding sides of the hexagon: this is the unique solution with the textblock lying within the page.  Since these are solutions of cubic equations, I have my doubts that a complete solution lies within the linear solving abilities of Metapost, but think there still might be a nice geometric construction.

Reference: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89925/6903) to the question: [Bringhurst chapter style in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88895/6903)

Comment: _What now?_ You might add information which dimensions you actually need. What is the mathematical, geometrical background of this? How are _x_, _y_ and _a_ defined? Anyway, if TikZ can draw it, it can tell you how long it is.

Comment: Is there actually a *unique* solution? The points *x* and *y* appear to be arbitrary and independent.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: If you require the page and text-area to be rectangular, and the lines to go through the points as specified, then there is a unique solutionk but it seems you must first write the equations implicitly and then solve... I can't find a good geometric solution.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: `x`, `y`, and `a` are implicitly defined by the geometric constraints in the picture and the constraints that the page and text-block are rectangular with vertical alignment.

Comment: We know the dimensions of the page and the text area as well?  Or just the page?

Comment: Well, the diagram really only gives you the relative proportions.  Bringhurst's actual page size is pretty close to `5.2in` wide and `9in` high.  This fixes all absolute scales.

Comment: Due to the hexagon `9in = 2*(5.2in*cos(30))` so one dimen is enough for that but that doesn't render the solution unique. It looks like there must be at least one other characteristic dimension to fix the text area relative to the page.

Comment: How are the points *x* and *y* defined? I suppose the angle of *x* must be 90°, right?

Comment: A couple more observations: (1) The angle ur-ul-a appears (empirically) to be 45 degrees; (b) In Bringhurst's drawing, one or two of the intersections at a single point (eg upper left corner of textblock) are (ahem) *approximate*?

Comment: @morbusg : Angle *x* is only 90° when x is at either ll or lr. At intermediate positions it is greater that 90°, with a maximum of around 98.2° [2 × arcsin(sqrt(1/1.75))]

Comment: As you all have been noticing, there are several near geometric coincidence.  For example `y`-`r` is almost parallel to `ul`-`a` (it is not), `a` is almost a midpoint of `lr`-`r` (it is not), 45º angles (there are not any) etc.  The solution does not seem to have any simple properties, but @percusse I am pretty sure that the solution is unique. I will try to provide a proof later.

Comment: @mforbes: Could you explain what `q` is and how you get the algebraic solution for `q`, `x` and `y`?

Comment: @Tobi `q` is just a number that makes the solution simpler. I found the algebraic solution by simply doing the vector algebra needed to construct the image and then solving the resulting equations using a symbolic algebra package like SymPy or Maple.   When I have some time, I will write this all up as a tugboat article, but time has been a bit short...

Comment: At typografie.info the user Wrzlprmft postet his arithmetic solution done with a python script: http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/31278-satzspiegel-nach-bringhurst/?p=176954

Comment: @mforbes: Thanks for the explanation (overhead it yesterday) does `q` have a geometrical meaning / representation in the image?

Comment: @Tobi: Not that I am aware of.  I just chose it to make the solutions have a simpler form.

Answer (score 12):

Just to get the ball rolling (and to get to play with MetaPost), here is what I have so far:
(**updated** with a few ideas I had, I still need to test out Barbara’s and mforbes’ hints and ideas)

```
beginfig(1);
  defaultscale := .8; % make the text a little smaller
  u := 1.5in;
  phi := 1.618033988749895;

  for i:= 0 upto 5: z.hexc[i] = right scaled u rotated (i*360/6); endfor;
  path hexa; hexa := for i:=0 upto5: z.hexc[i]--endfor cycle;
  fill hexa withcolor .9[green,white]; draw hexa;
  dotlabel.rt("r", z.hexc0); dotlabel.urt("ur", z.hexc1);
  dotlabel.ulft("ul", z.hexc2); dotlabel.lft("l", z.hexc3);
  dotlabel.llft("ll", z.hexc4); dotlabel.lrt("lr", z.hexc5);

  path recto; recto := z.hexc1--z.hexc2--z.hexc4--z.hexc5--cycle;
  path verso; verso := recto shifted (-1u,0);
  for i:=verso,recto:%,recto shifted (1u,0):
    draw i withpen pencircle scaled 1.2; endfor;

  picture mforbes; mforbes :=
  image(
    z.a   = (1.27106916798686u, 0.469505571318668u);
    z.tll = (0.117300021398114u, 0.294835256924744u);
    z.tlr = (0.798192881206518u, 0.294835256924744u);
    z.tur = (0.798192881206518u, 1.61553741320908u);
    z.tul = (0.117300021398114u, 1.61553741320908u);
    z.x   = (0.435936138301u, 0);
    z.y   = (0.689095323638u, 1.73205080756888u);
    dotlabels.lrt(a,tll,tlr,tur,tul,x,y);
  );
  drawoptions( withcolor .5 red );
  draw mforbes shifted llcorner recto;

  % Bringhurst's lines:
  draw z.hexc1--z.hexc3--z.x shifted llcorner recto--z.hexc0--
    z.y shifted llcorner recto--z.hexc4--z.a shifted llcorner recto--z.hexc2
    %dashed evenly
    ;
  drawoptions();

  % Van de Graaf: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_page_construction
  picture van_de_Graaf; van_de_Graaf := image(
    path Van_de_Graaf[];

    Van_de_Graaf0 := ulcorner verso--lrcorner recto--ulcorner recto
      --llcorner verso--urcorner recto;
    draw Van_de_Graaf0 dashed evenly;

    % subpath (0,1) is the first line, (1,2) is the second, etc.
    z.vdG0 = (subpath(3,4) of Van_de_Graaf0) intersectiontimes
      (subpath(3,4) of hexa);
    z.vdG1 = point xpart z.vdG0 of subpath(3,4) of hexa; % show this point
    z.vdG2 = point ypart z.vdG0 of subpath(1,2) of hexa; % on this path
    % ypart(z.vdG1) == xpart(z.vdG1) ?
    dotlabel.lft("vdG1", z.vdG1);
    dotlabel.urt("vdG2", z.vdG2);
    % Close, but no cigar. Back to the drawing board.

    % van de Graaf continued to project lines from the intersections:
    z.vdG3 = (subpath(1,2) of Van_de_Graaf0) intersectionpoint
      (subpath(3,4) of Van_de_Graaf0);
    z.vdG4 = (xpart z.vdG3, ypart urcorner recto);
    z.vdG5 = (subpath(0,1) of Van_de_Graaf0) intersectionpoint
      (subpath(2,3) of Van_de_Graaf0);
    z.vdG6 = (xpart z.vdG5, ypart urcorner verso);
    dotlabels.ulft(vdG3, vdG4, vdG5, vdG6);
    Van_de_Graaf1 := (z.vdG5)--(z.vdG4);
    Van_de_Graaf2 := (z.vdG6)--(z.vdG3);
    drawoptions( dashed evenly );
    draw Van_de_Graaf1; draw Van_de_Graaf2;
    drawoptions();
    % Nope. Not even close.

    z.guess_a = whatever[z.vdG6,z.vdG3] = whatever[z.hexc0,z.hexc5];
    % Did I hit it? Pleasepleasepleasepleaseplease...
    dotlabel.lrt("guess a", z.guess_a);
    % Nope.

    % That intersection of cross-page vdG's looks promising
  );
  draw van_de_Graaf withcolor .5 white;

  z.golden1 = point 1/phi of subpath(5,4) of hexa;
  z.golden2 = point 1/phi of subpath(2,1) of hexa;
  drawoptions( withcolor .5[green,red] );
  dotlabel.bot(btex $\phi$ etex, z.golden1);
  dotlabel.top(btex $\phi$ etex, z.golden2);
  drawoptions();

endfig;
end
```

(I haven't used MetaPost much, so if you have suggestions on improving, please share)

[image]

Comment: This is the type of construction that I tried, but as you see, unless you know a couple of exact values beforehand, such constructions will not give a properly oriented rectangular text-block.  The constraint of a rectangular (and vertical) text-block defines the (unique?) solution.  My question is: can one elegantly construct and solve for this solution geometrically without first having to know one or more of the special parameters?  (I was hoping that MetaPost would allow me to form the constraints, and would then solve the system for me, but I still don't see how.)

Comment: @mforbes, Yeah I was merely trying to get people to see this question. I'll put some juicy bounty up to further tingle people's interest. MetaPost has a system for solving linear equations for example with its `whatever`-notation (so for example `whatever[z3,z3]`), but I don't know how to tell it the rectangular constraints. Though, after seeing some jaw-dropping examples done with MetaPost I have a feeling it is doable.

Comment: I am still hoping that it is doable, but unfortunately, I think that – unless some geometric trick/feature is found – the resulting equations are going to be non-linear. (P.S. You can remove `a` as a mystery point by constraining right text-block border to be vertical. P.P.S. your labelling is a little different than mine: `ll` etc. in my diagram are the page, not text boundaries.)

Comment: after some careful measuring, i have concluded that if you drop a line down from y to intersect the line drawn tangent to the top of the top circle, you will have a square in the upper-right hand corner of the page.  the length of a side is the sum of the top and right-hand margins, and the height of the top margin equals the width of the left margin.  are these dimensions useful to help with a construction?  (the only parallel lines are the opposite sides of the hexagon, the opposite edges of the paper and text area, and the lines from the circles, which are horizontal.)

Comment: You could possibly use `dotprod` to access the constraint that the sides of the type area form a rectangle (i.e. `dotprod = 0` for adjacent sides).  It seems that you can use `whatevers` in dot product expressions.  I played around with it for a bit but because I have no idea what I'm doing, I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Your square is very close to a square, but is not exactly a square (the slope of the diagonal is `1.0147...`).  @ScottH.: That is the idea I had, but the problem is that the whatever `whatever`s I use, I end up with non-linear equations.  Given the exact relationships outlined in my update, I suspect that one may be able to construct `x` from `y` using `whatevers` but think that getting `y` might be out of the question.

Comment: @mforbes -- thanks for the feedback.  i've not used metapost enough (nor metafont either) to be able to check that out myself.  but i like this puzzle, and think it would make an interesting tugboat article.  would you be willing to write up something along this line?

Comment: @ScottH. -- a comment addressed to you was included in one addressed to me; since by the comment rules (as i understand them) only one person gets notified per comment, i'd like to alert you to yours, just in case.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Sure. I was hoping to also get some TikZ gurus chiming in here since I have really not worked with it much beyond my problem exposition, but I think I could work something out... of course, unless someone comes up with a solution, it will have to stand as an unsolved puzzle:-)