# Chapter alignment, title on the line

Tags: chapters

Im trying to recreate this ([Chapter style like this without memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101272/chapter-style-like-this-without-memoir)) chapter, however it is not quite working as it says in the comments. I am now doing this, for numbered chapters, however I cannot get the chapter title on the line, instead of right as in the picture. The chapter title should thus be on the line, as far to the right as possible. Also, I have no clue what the 110 stands for (I adjusted it, but nothing changes), so if anyone knows, it would really help me understand the code haha! In addition the fontsize of the chapter name does not seem to change as expected when I change it (I do this in the \normalfont\Large\sffamily by changing \Large to different sizes, but it only changes a little when I change it to \HUGE for instance. It was in the original code done with #1, but I get a "1" in the pdf.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\Large\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[t]{\chapnumb}{%
   \fontsize{100}{110}\selectfont\thechapter}%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{
    \raggedleft
    \hfill{\LARGE}
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.9pt}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something along these lines.

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
   \makebox[\chapnumb][r]{\fontsize{100}{0}\selectfont\thechapter}%
   \ \hrulefill\ %
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
   \hrulefill\ %
  }

\newlength{\chapnumb}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\chapnumb}{\fontsize{100}{0}\sffamily00}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\chapter*{Introduction}
\chapter{Introduction}

Some text follows

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I used the trick of `\let`ting `\clearpage` to `\relax` just to show together a numbered and an unnumbered chapter header.

Modify to suit you.

[image]

What does the `110` stand for? It sets the baseline skip for the paragraphs to be set with font size 100pt, but it's completely irrelevant as you're not actually making a paragraph. I used `0`, but `42` or `1234` would have been the same.