# Chapter title on the line

Tags: sectioning, chapters

Im trying this code for a pretty chapter title: (http://texnorte.blogspot.com/2012/06/styling-my-sectionchapter.html), however I cannot get the chapter title on the line instead of next to it. It should be on the right of the page, as in the link. Can someone please help me :)

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}\thechapter.~}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}\Huge}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a *complete* code? Also, I'm not too sure of waht you want: should the rule start at the left margin or at the beginning of the sheet ot paper? Should the number be at  the left margin and the title aligned at the right margin, or both at the right margin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chapter alignment, title on the line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547341/chapter-alignment-title-on-the-line)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I've well understood what you want, but I propose some like this (with the default `hang` style ):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}\thechapter.~}
  {15pt}
  {\Huge}[\vskip -1.5ex\hspace*{-110pt}\color{IndianRed}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}}
  {-15pt}
  {\Huge}[\vskip -1.5ex\hspace*{-110pt}\color{IndianRed}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Method}

\chapter*{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]