# Change the chapter style in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, scrbook

Is there a way to change the chapter style in `scrbook` like in `memoir` with `\chapterstyle{}`?

Comment: You see, people either use memoir or KOMA-script, rarely both. If you offer a picture or a description of what you want, for readers who are not familiar with memoir, but with KOMA-script, you'll improve the likelihood to get a good anwswer.

Comment: @KeksDose Sorry, if the question was unclear. I was asking if there was a similar scrbook command to memoir's `\chapterstyle{}`.

Comment: I have no idea, what `\chapterstyle{}` is doing, and a repetition of what you want does clearly not improve my knowledge.

Comment: There is no `\chapterstyle` equivalent for the KOMA classes. Maybe have a look at mforbes' answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88895/5049 and my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94430/5049 for inspiration how to modify KOMA's chapter headings

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK KOMA-Script does not provide something like `\chapterstyle`. Nevertheless there are some options that influence the output and behaviour of chapters,
see Section ["3.16 Structuring of Documents"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), e.g.:

- Options, where the chapter starts: `open={any|right|left}`
- Prefix: `chapterprefix={true|false}`, `appendixprefix={true|false}`
- Font sizes and other formatting of the chapter title:
  `headings={big|normal|small|...}`
- Options for what goes into the table of contents/header line.
- Number format (with/without dot at end, ...)

Comment: There are also the hooks `\chapterheadstartvskip` and `\chapterheadendvskip` which can be redefined. Per default they are defined to some `\vspace*{...}` (depending on the `headings` option)

Comment: Is it possible to use `fncychap`? Or is that not a good idea?