# coffin--structuring and typesetting

Tags: xcoffins

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{333333}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\begin{document}

\SetHorizontalCoffin\OutputCoffin{}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\RedCoffin
            {\color{red!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[vc,hc]\RedCoffin[vc,hc]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\BlueCoffin
            {\color{blue!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\RedCoffin-vc,\RedCoffin-hc]
            \BlueCoffin[b,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\GreenCoffin
            {\color{green!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\BlueCoffin-vc,\BlueCoffin-hc]
            \GreenCoffin[b,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\YellowCoffin
            {\color{yellow!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\GreenCoffin-vc,\GreenCoffin-hc]
            \YellowCoffin[b,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin \OrangeCoffin
            {\color{orange!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\BlueCoffin-t,\BlueCoffin-l]
            \OrangeCoffin[b,r]
\TypesetCoffin\OutputCoffin
\end{document}
```

Based on the documentation of coffins I was trying to compile the above code--how do i complete it??

output is as under
[image]

courtesy @FrankMittelbach for his answer @https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44159/197451

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{333333}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\NewCoffin \RedCoffin
\NewCoffin \BlueCoffin
\NewCoffin \GreenCoffin
\NewCoffin \YellowCoffin
\NewCoffin \OrangeCoffin
\NewCoffin \OutputCoffin

\begin{document}

\SetHorizontalCoffin\OutputCoffin{}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\RedCoffin
            {\color{red!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[vc,hc]\RedCoffin[vc,hc]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\BlueCoffin
            {\color{blue!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\RedCoffin-vc,\RedCoffin-hc]
            \BlueCoffin[b,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\GreenCoffin
            {\color{green!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\BlueCoffin-vc,\BlueCoffin-hc]
            \GreenCoffin[b,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\YellowCoffin
            {\color{yellow!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\GreenCoffin-vc,\GreenCoffin-hc]
            \YellowCoffin[b,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin \OrangeCoffin
            {\color{orange!20!white}\rule{0.2 in}{0.2 in}}
                \JoinCoffins\OutputCoffin[\BlueCoffin-t,\BlueCoffin-l]
            \OrangeCoffin[b,r]
\TypesetCoffin\OutputCoffin
\end{document}
```

got it !!!

also deleted the white color to get deeper colored squares
[image]