# Right aligned Title with image on the left

Tags: titles

I want to make a title that will follow the following structure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}% just to show the page margins

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove demo option in actual document

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{yourimage}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}\raggedleft
Yesterday,\\
all my troubles seemed so far away\\
Now it looks as though they're here to stay\\
Oh, I believe in yesterday.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(code found here [How do I put an image on the left of right-aligned text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41305/how-do-i-put-an-image-on-the-left-of-right-aligned-text))

That is the text of the `\title` will be right aligned and there will be an image on the left of the text

How is it possible this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AboAmmar I gave this MWE as an indication of the title structure I want to achieve. The title's text will right aligned and the image on the left.

Comment: Will the title be the text Yesterday all my troubles... or will it be something else?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily No something else. If the way I asked the question is misleading I will modify it.

Comment: @Dimitris - Yes, I mean do you need this for a title page using `\maketitle` or something else, the question is not very specific.

Comment: @AboAmmar Yes I want it for a title page using `maketitle`. Searching here for relevant questions I found the code and the image and I thought will be helpful to explain what I am looking for:-)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the answer.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}% just to show the page margins
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \title{Paper Title}
    \author{Your name}
    \date{\today}
    \noindent\adjustbox{valign = t}{%
    \includegraphics[width = 0.3\textwidth, height = 3in]{yourimage}}\hfill%Image
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}\raggedleft
        Yesterday,\\
        all my troubles seemed so far away\\
        Now it looks as though they're here to stay\\
        Oh, I believe in yesterday.\\        
        \begingroup
        \let\center\flushright
        \maketitle
        \endgroup
    \end{minipage}\\
    Stuff stuff stuff...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to reverse the text and image positions (text left aligned and image on the right) what should I do?

Comment: Ok, I found it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\makeatletter         
\def\@maketitle{
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.69\textwidth}
\raggedleft{\bfseries\@title}\par\medskip(\@author,
\@date)\end{minipage}\vspace{3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Yesterday,\\
all my troubles seemed so far away.\\
Now it looks as though they're here to stay\\
Oh, I believe in yesterday.}

\author{The Beatles}

\date{1965}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, just wrap what you wrote inside a `\title{..}` command. Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}% just to show the page margins
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove demo option in actual document

\begin{document}

\title{\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{yourimage}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}\raggedleft
Yesterday,\\
all my troubles seemed so far away\\
Now it looks as though they're here to stay\\
Oh, I believe in yesterday.
\end{minipage}}
\date{}
\author{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```