# Make a two column with one column image and other text

Tags: two-column

How do I make a two column minisection in my latex document where the left hand column would be an image and the right hand column would be some accompanying text?

Comment: there are two "obvious" approaches: using minipages (see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14238/579) for ideas) or tabular.  minipages probably wins; [more information on minipage alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/579) here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried minipages, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

The mulitcol package will do the trick for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\parindent0em

\lipsum[4]

\begin{multicols}{2}[\columnsep2em] 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
\columnbreak

Here is the short text that accompanies my figure.
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is shown without horizontal gaps, but they would be easy enough to insert.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}%
\parbox[b]{.5\textwidth}{Here is the short text that accompanies my
figure.}

\lipsum[4]

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}%
\parbox[b]{.5\textwidth}{
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
Here is the long text that accompanies my figure.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]